# comparing Two NSDate objects not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning about how to compare `NSDate` objects with the `isEqualToDateDate` method. I don't get why this simple test does not return true and print out the `NSLog`. Thanks in advance

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSDate *myDate =    [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:4000000];
    NSDate *otherDate = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:4000000];

     NSLog(@"myDate    %@",myDate);
     NSLog(@"otherDate %@",otherDate);

    if ([myDate isEqualToDate:otherDate]) {

        NSLog(@"The dates are the same");
    };

    [myDate release];
    [otherDate release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe, and this may be wrong, that since you are using `initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow` that the objects are being allocated at slightly different times, thus making them unequal.

Comment: yea I think you might be right - I've changed the method to the initWithTimeIntervalSince1970 and all is fine. What I don't get is what is this method  for if it always returns false. Any further help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Both dates are indeed slightly different. Quick example to show the difference:

```
NSDate *one = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:4000000];
NSDate *two = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:4000000];

NSComparisonResult difference = [two compare:one];

NSLog(@"Date one: %@",one);
NSLog(@"Date two: %@",two);

NSLog(@"Exact difference: %ld",difference);
```

Output:

```
Date one: 2012-01-03 07:47:40 +0000
Date two: 2012-01-03 07:47:40 +0000
Exact difference: 1
```

**EDIT**

`isEqualToDate:` returns `true` in the following example:

```
NSDate *one = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:4000000];
NSDate *two = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:4000000];
if ([one isEqualToDate:two]) NSLog(@"Equal");
```

Output:

```
Equal
```

Comment: looking at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult 1 means it is ordered Descending

Comment: Thanks Anne but wheres the difference - they print out the same !!

Comment: They are different in milliseconds

Comment: those sneaky milliseconds !! - Ok, so whats the point of this method ?  If It returns a BOOL that will always be false !

Comment: sure. when dealing with time, you will have to define, how accurate the comparison should be.

Comment: Added example to show `isEqualToDate:` does not always return `false`.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect: `isEqualToDate:` is checking for exact time. The reason your code work is the way of your instantiation: Timeintervals are defined to be a second, so in both date there are no milliseconds or nanoseconds.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You're indeed right, I removed the invalid part of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help